# Using AEC(webrtc) instead of AECM(webrtc)

Tags: webrtc, audio-processing, aec

I used `aecm(webrtc)` on my ARM-based embedded device for voice communication. Now, I'm trying to change `aecm` to `aec` for double-talk echo cancellation.

It's simple in `aecm`:

```
WebRtcAecm_Create()->WebRtcAecm_Init()->WebRtcAecm_BufferFarend()->WebRtcAecm_Process().
```

And all `data(near, far, out)` formats are 16bit signed short. However, just changing functions from `WebRtcAecm_* to WebRtcAec_*` and signed-short data to float(divided by 32768) didn't work.

I tried to find some examples in audio_processing `unittest`, but couldn't find any. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC AEC just compare Farend Buffer and NearBuffer extracted from Mic and remove Echo in NearBuffer based on Farend. So Echo you want to clear must exist in Farend Buffer, then AEC could remove it. Please check your device latency, Basically Farend Buffer only maintain 128m/s length.